# Can I detect the Java version from native c++

Tags: java, c++, version

I'm writing a complex setup/installer application in native C++/MFC.  I would very much like to be able to detect the version of Java that is installed (if any).

Is this possible, and so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running `java -version` in a subprocess (reading that process's output with pipe) and parsing the results (if any); or, you could mess with Windows' registry (which feels even more complicated, but may be less kludgy).

Comment: I managed to find and parse the version information in SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\BrowserJavaVersion

Thank you

Comment: Would a "launch Java DLL" from within the C++ program be feasible?  Should give a good idea what the default JVM is on the machine.

Comment: Browser version could not be the real system version...I would suggest you use @emg-2 answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Fork a process that executes the following command: `java -version`.  Collect the output and parse it.  It looks something like the following:

```
java version "1.5.0_16"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_16-b06-284)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_16-133, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is written to stderr.  You need to collect the stderr output and parse it.

Comment: I'll add that you probably need the assistance of a shell on the platform, or else executing 'java' will do nothing since there is presumably no 'java' binary in your current directory.

On *nix you would execute something like "sh -c 'java -version'" to make sure you actually execute java from the path. I am not sure of the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: @Sean Owen: Windows normally automatically looks in the process' PATH environment variable, without the assistance of any shell.

Comment: How does one go about collecting that output?  I've been attempting to do that by redirecting STDOUT to a text file, then parsing the text file.  However, it doesn't seem to be using STDOUT as the data still goes to the screen instead of the file...

Comment: Doh.  Nevermind.  For whatever reason it does screen output through STDERR instead of STDOUT.  Argh.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the registry. You're programming windows, so do it windows-way. Registry-anxiety is irrational.

Registry key for the version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion
```

Information how to get the value from the registry can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/net/cplus/article.php/3449721#enumerateValues).

Information about other java related registry keys can be found [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/registry.html).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind also that it is entirely possible to have more than one JRE installed on a machine at the same time. If your install program detects more than one JRE, it should offer a choice to the user rather than assuming that one of them (eg. the latest one) should be the one which will be used by your app.